# Display four files side by side

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How to display four files side by side using bash please? 
The file names are: data2 data4 data5 and data6.

I tried

`paste data2 data4 data5 data6 |awk -F"," '{printf("%-50s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5)}' > data3`.

This almost works right but for some reason it is not outputting the last column of each file (the last column of each file is just a comma ","). I need the last column to be included too.

Thanks.

Comment: How many columns are in the file? Anything more than 5 and you'll miss data on that output. If you mean you want a comma after the fifth field data then just stick one in your printf at the end. Also that `awk` looks like it should actually only be printing out two columns of data.

Comment: You're telling `awk` that commas are field separators, so it doesn't keep the commas around.  You're also printing just `$1` and `$2` because there's only two `%s` specifications in the format (it ignores `$3` to `$5`).  Tell `awk` to use the tab character that `paste` uses.

Comment: `paste` alone will display the 4 files side-by-side so what is it you;re trying to do with the awk command? Show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling `awk` that commas are field separators, so it doesn't keep the commas around.  You're also printing just `$1` and `$2` because there's only two `%s` specifications in the format (it ignores `$3` to `$5`).  Tell `awk` to use the tab character that `paste` uses.

```
paste data2 data4 data5 data6 |
awk -F $'\t' '{printf("%-30s %-30s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

The `$'\t'` is a Bash extension called [ANSI C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).  If you're not using Bash, use `-F '        '` where there is a tab character (possibly entered using <kbd>Control-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) between the two single quotes.

This code does assume there are no tabs in the data files.  If there are tabs, then choose a different character that is not present in any of the files as a delimiter — perhaps <kbd>Control-A</kbd> — and tell both `paste` and `awk` to use that instead:

```
paste -d $'\001' data2 data4 data5 data6 |
awk -F $'\001' '{printf("%-30s %-30s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` solution

```
awk -F, -v OFS="\t" '
  ARGIND == 1 {f1[FNR]=$0;c=c<FNR?FNR:c;next}
  ARGIND == 2 {f2[FNR]=$0;c=c<FNR?FNR:c;next}
  ARGIND == 3 {f3[FNR]=$0;c=c<FNR?FNR:c;next}
  ARGIND == 3 {f4[FNR]=$0;c=c<FNR?FNR:c;next}
END { 
  for (i=1;i<=c;i++) print f1[i],f2[i],f3[i],f4[i]}
' data2 data4 data5 data6
```

It does read every file into different arrays using `ARGIND`, then
print it out in correct format.